# How can I establish a connection to a file?

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file in the same folder as my R Script file. I can view the file when I click on it in the folder. I tried opening the file using seg_data <- read.csv(file = "SegmentationData.csv",row.names=1)

I receive the following error response:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'SegmentationData.csv': No such file or directory

[Screenshot of my R script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3N5m.jpg)

Comment: Maybe add the full path. See current with `getwd()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS GKi mentioned, you need to tell R where you want it to read the csv file from.

if your csv file path is C:\Project\SegmentationData.csv, then you need to set your current working directory to it with :

```
setwd("C:\\Project")
```

Notice the double `\\` instead of just a single.
Then you can use your function call:

```
seg_data <- read.csv(file = "SegmentationData.csv",row.names=1)
```